# Angular 2 ngFor conditional placement

Tags: angular, ngfor

In my angular 2 app I have array with some items and would like to put each item to specific place depending on condition.

This is example template:

```
<div>
  <div>_place if 1 condition</div>
  <div>_place if 2 condition</div>
  ...
  <div>_place if n condition</div>
</div>
```

So, I would like to put array items to 1 place if 1 condition, to 2 place if 2 ... to n if n.
Is there way to do this with ngFor or some else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I would filter the array! In `ngOnInit()` set variables equal to the result of each filter. This will sort the values of a single array into multiple arrays based on conditions in the filter.

```
ngOnInit(){
    let div1Values = this.records.filter((item) => {
            return (item.CustomerKey === 0? item : null);
    })
    let div2Values = this.records.filter((item) => {
            return (item.IsActive? item : null);
    })
}
```

Then bind to these new arrays in the template:

```
<div>
  <div *ngFor="let record of div1Values">{{record}}</div>
  <div *ngFor="let item of div2Values">{{item}}</div>
  ...
  <div *ngFor="let value of divNValues">{{value}}</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use something like below

```
<div *ngFor="let value of values">
  <div *ngIf="value == Condition1">_place if 1 condition</div>
  <div *ngIf="value == Condition2">_place if 2 condition</div>
  ...
  <div *ngIf="value == ConditionN">_place if n condition</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I would like add value into `<div *ngIf="value == Condition1">_place if 1 condition</div>` container, but *ngIf will render container every time if condition is true.

Comment: OK I don't see any problem in rerendering though but alternately you can use <div [hidden]="!condition">Some content</div> that won't re-render